# Pass process.env variables to protractor cli

Tags: node.js, protractor

How can I pass in custom Node process.env variables on the protractor command line when I run my tests?

My protractor E2E tests using Angular work great from IntelliJ. In my IntelliJ Run/Debug configuration, I provide environment variables, such as USER_EMAIL, USER_PASSWORD, APP_URL and some others. I want to do this with the protractor cli so I can run these tests from terminal.

I can run tests from terminal only when I edit the protractor.conf.js file. I am not sure of how to specify the process.env variables on the command line. I do not want to edit protractor.conf.js as it is shared by many engineers.

Is there a way to pass in these process.env variables using the protractor cli?

This is the cli command I am running.
protractor protractor.conf.js --specs ./test/ui/my-tests/myspec.ts

Comment: What's your terminal? Bash syntax for specifying env var for the session is `export FOO=bar` and for a command `FOO=bar cmd`

Comment: ITerm2 for OSX, thanks.

Comment: Bash syntax will work

Comment: Do I run "export FOO=bar" as a single command, then I run my "protractor protractor.conf.js ..." command after it? If so, that is not working for me.

Comment: Working now! Awesome, thanks. I must have had a typo. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

use [cross-env](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env), you can set the environment variable in one command line together with actual command to execute, no need to export/set environment varaible ahead actual command. And cross-env is cross platform.

Example:

```
cross-env USER_EMAIL=abc@123.com APP_URL=http://abc.123.com protractor protractor.conf.js --specs ./test/ui/my-tests/myspec.ts
```

Comment: Thank you for providing this solution. Export works just fine for me, so I am not going to install cross-env until I do need that functionality.